# Running google analytics on intranet pages

Tags: google-analytics, mediawiki

I have two sites internally,

one with apps: `http://myapps.mycompany.com`, the url internally is just `http://myapps`
But it logs even if the user uses the shortcut.

But that is not the case with the other one which is a mediawiki (with ldap).

`http://mywiki.mycomapny.com` where the shortcut is `http://mywiki` . It only logs if the users uses the extended url (which no one does). What may be the issue here?

I am using this media wiki extension: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Google_Analytics_Integration

Comment: Are you sure the intranet users can contact the Google Analytics domain?